# mock in unittest Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to replace randint in the method multi with 'mock' in Python. My code doesn't work. How can I make it work?

```
from random import randint
import unittest
from unittest import mock


class Calculator:

    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number
        self.number2 = randint(1, 5)

    def multi(self):
        return self.number * self.number2


class CalculatorTest(unittest.TestCase):

    NUMBER = Calculator(3)

    @mock.patch('random.randint', return_value=4)
    def test_multi(self):
        actual_result = self.NUMBER.multi()
        expected_result = 12
        self.assertEqual(actual_result, expected_result,
                         f'Actual result {actual_result}, expected {expected_result}')
```

Comment: What are the requirements for you program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `randint` when `NUMBER` is defined, not when you call its `multi` method. The patch is too late. Instead, define `NUMBER` in the test itself. Further, since you used `from random import randint`, the name to patch is `randint`, not `random.randint`.

```
class CalculatorTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('randint', return_value=4)
    def test_multi(self, mock_rand):
        NUMBER = Calculator(3)
        actual_result = NUMBER.multi()
        expected_result = 12
        self.assertEqual(actual_result, expected_result,
                         f'Actual result {actual_result}, expected {expected_result}')
```

If `NUMBER` *must* be defined as class attribute (though that would be atypical), you can use `mock.patch` as a context manager rather than a decorator.

```
class CalculatorTest(unittest.TestCase):

    with mock.patch('randint', return_value=4)
        NUMBER = Calculator(3)

    def test_multi(self):
        actual_result = self.NUMBER.multi()
        expected_result = 12
        self.assertEqual(actual_result, expected_result,
                         f'Actual result {actual_result}, expected {expected_result}')
```

More commonly, though, you would use the `setUp` method to define a fixture, rather than sharing an instance across tests. You can either decorate `setUp` or us the context manager.

```
class CalculatorTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        with mock.patch('randint', return_value=4):
            self.NUMBER = Calculator(3)

    ...
```

or

```
class CalculatorTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('randint', return_value=4)
    def setUp(self, mock_rand):
        self.NUMBER = Calculator(3)

    ...
```